# Where can I download Sp5 for Visual Studio 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I can download SP6 but the bean counters say it has to be SP5. Does anyone have a link to a download for VS 6.0 SP5?

Comment: This perhaps? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=bf9a24f9-b5c5-48f4-8edd-cdf2d29a79d5

Comment: @RichardOD: Thanks, but thats the re-distributable, I need the SP for Visual Studio.

Comment: @RichardOD Download is not available anymore ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filewatcher.com has about 10 ftp servers listed with links to vs6sp5.exe.

As a comment below notes filewatcher.com is no longer. If anyone shows up actually looking for Service Pack 5 the link in Tony Day's answer is still active. Visual Basic 6 Service Pack 6 can be still be downloaded from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721).

Comment: Link is broken ;(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[External Source](http://visual-studio-6-sp5.en.malavida.com/)

I don't know if the Merge Modules will help you:

[Visual Studio 6.0 Merge Modules](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=9f10ca3b-44da-4edf-a5da-1aeaf5c88165)

Otherwise, I would contact MSDN support, they should get back to you quickly, there may be a fault in why it is not available, or they may link you to the resource.

Comment: Been there, I get "We are sorry to inform you the Visual Studio 6 SP5 ISN'T AVAILABLE from the Developers/Distributors server."

Comment: Would the "mal" prefix to this site's name be relevant?

Comment: @nobugs: What do you mean? My IP was selected as "a potential winner", how lucky am I? It'll be the lottery next!

Comment: P.S. Forgot to put <scarcasm> tags on the above.

Comment: Apologies it must be deprecated. It may be worth speaking to the bean counters again. Microsoft may have sufficient reasons to stop the distribution of SP5.